# IronPython WPF project cannot find ICO file at run-time

Tags: wpf, ironpython

Using IronPython and WPF in VS2017:

I have added an icon located in my code source directory to the XAML Window tag. I've also included the file in the project in the solution explorer. If I use the full file C: drive file path, it works. But, I need to use a relative path because it will be run on other computers.

If I try Icon="../xxx.ico" the file isn't found (squiggly line, "Cannot find...).

If I try Icon="xxx.ico" the file IS found while editing, however at run-time I get an exception

> Exception: Failed to create a 'Icon' from the text 'xxx.ico'.

It seems that the Python interpreter cannot locate it.

What do I need to do so that it is found at run-time?

Comment: I already tried that, just in case, and it didn't make any difference. It is set to Resource. But IronPython of course runs through an interpreter, and isn't built.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this same issue myself and have found a solution, albeit a little late!

It does indeed seem that `IronPython` interprets the field as text unless it determines a valid `uri` is present.

We can get around this via code, a bit of reading into `c#` and how it handles `icons` was needed here;

- Dynamically setting our path and file
  location at runtime.
- Create a [`BitmapImage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapframe?view=netcore-3.1)
  after casting our file location as a [`c# Uri`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri?view=netcore-3.1)
- Update our `xaml` to give our `window` an `x:Name=""`
- Set our `window.Icon` to the `BitmapImage` we defined earlier

---

XAML

```
<Window 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xml:lang="en-AU"
    x:Name="window">
</Window>
```

Code behind

```
import os
import clr

clr.AddReference('System')

from System import Uri
from System.Windows.Media.Imaging import BitmapImage

class Application(Window):

    def __init__(self):  

        ## Set our icon file path dynamically based off working directory ##
        icon = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'app-logo.ico')

        ## Define BitmapImage from Uri(filepath) ##
        self.icon = BitmapImage(Uri(icon))

        ## Load our wpf component, defined under self.ui to allow easy access ##
        self.ui = wpf.LoadComponent(self, 'application.xaml')

        ## Set our XAML x:Name="window"'s Icon field to our BitmapImage
        self.ui.window.Icon = self.icon
```

Thats it! Our Icon is now set and working as intended.

Taskbar:

[image]

Application Icon:

[image]